# I cannot see the menu that I create in my theme, in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I register my main menu in my wordpress theme, but when i save and i try to see in my admin panel, 
does not appear.

The code:

```
function games_register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'main-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' )
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'games_register_my_menus' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action is too soon. You need to wait until the menu is set up.

Change

```
add_action( 'init', 'games_register_my_menus' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'games_register_my_menus' );
```